# timeout in shell script and report those input with timeout

Tags: linux, shell, timeout

I would like to conduct analysis using program Arlsumstat_64bit with thousand of input files.

Arlsumstat_64bit reads input files (.arp) and write result file (sumstat.out).
Each input will append new line on the result file (sumstat.out) based on the argument "0 1"
Therefore, I wrote a shell script to execute all the input (*.arp) in the same folder.
However, if the input files contain error, the shell script will be stuck without any subsequently process. Therefore, I found a command with "timeout" to deal my issue.
I made a shell script as following

```
#!/bin/bash

for sp in $(ls *.arp) ; 
do

echo "process start: $sp"


timeout 10 arlsumstat_64bit ${sp}.arp sumstat.out 1 0 

        rm -r ${sp}.res

        echo "process done: $sp"


done
```

However, I still need to know which input files failed.
How could make a list telling me which input files are "timeout"?

Comment: Suggested improvements: Use `for sp in *.arp` instead of using the output of `ls`. `$sp` will include the `.arp`, so it should probably be `arlsumstat_64bit ${sp} sumstat.out 1 0` and `rm -r ${sp%.arp}.res`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the man page for the `timeout` command http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html

> If the command times out, and --preserve-status is not set, then exit
>          with status 124.  Otherwise, exit with the status of COMMAND.  If no
>          signal is specified, send the TERM signal upon timeout.  The TERM
>          signal kills any process that does not block or catch that signal.
>          It may be necessary to use the KILL (9) signal, since this signal
>          cannot be caught, in which case the exit status is 128+9 rather than
>          124.

You should find out which exit codes are possible for the program `arlsumstat_64bit`. I assume it should exit with status 0 on success. Otherwise the script below will not work. If you need to distinguish between timeout and other errors it should not use exit status `124` or which is used by `timeout` to indicate a timeout. So you can check the exit status of your command to distinguish between success, error or timeout as necessary.

To keep the script simple I assume you don't need to distingish between timeout and other errors.

I added some comments where I modified your script to improve it or to show alternatives.

```
#!/bin/bash

# don't parse the output of ls
for sp in *.arp
do

    echo "process start: $sp"

    # instead of using "if timeout 10 arlsumstat_64bit ..." you could also run
    # timeout 10 arlsumstat_64bit...  and check the value of `$?` afterwards,
    # e.g. if you want to distinguish between error and timeout.

    # $sp will already contain .arp so ${sp}.arp is wrong
    # use quotes in case a file name contains spaces
    if timeout 10 arlsumstat_64bit "${sp}" sumstat.out 1 0 
    then
        echo "process done: $sp"
    else
        echo "processing failed or timeout: $sp"
    fi

    # If the result for foo.arp is foo.res, the .arp must be removed
    # If it is foo.arp.res, rm -r "${sp}.res" would be correct
    # use quotes
    rm -r "${sp%.arp}.res"

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work for you:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  for sp in $(ls *.arp) ; 
  do
  echo "process start: $sp"
  timeout 10 arlsumstat_64bit ${sp}.arp sumstat.out 1 0 
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "process done sucessfully: $sp"
  else
    echo "process failed: $sp"
  fi
  echo "Deleting ${sp}.res"
  rm -r ${sp}.res
  done
```

Comment: It should be `if [ $? -eq 0 ]` . I suggest to indent the lines in the `for` loop body to make the script more readable.